# NextJS dev server constantly keep disconnecting

Tags: javascript, next.js

## Problem

I have a NextJS project that i am currently working on, its smooth sailing but every once in a while, whenever i update my code there has been random occurences of my dev server disconnecting with the following message:

```
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (D:\vsc\msaf-next\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\undici\index.js:1:26669)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async invokeRequest (D:\vsc\msaf-next\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\server-ipc\invoke-request.js:17:12)
    at async invokeRender (D:\vsc\msaf-next\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:254:29)
    at async handleRequest (D:\vsc\msaf-next\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:447:24)
    at async requestHandler (D:\vsc\msaf-next\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:464:13)
    at async Server.<anonymous> (D:\vsc\msaf-next\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js:117:13) {
  cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:53023
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1247:16) {
    errno: -4078,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 53023
  }
}
```

I am currently using Next 13.4.19 and Javascript. I haven't tried anything because i don't really know where to start, but if you have any hint/solution/same problem please let me know.

Comment: It was happening for me from version 13.4.11 I'm now on 13.4.19 and it still persists.

Comment: They are investigating this issue: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/54708
Do you see ''The server is running out of memory, restarting to free up memory.' above the error message you mentioned whenever the crash happens?
It seems to be related to a memory leak issue.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else stumbles on this. I had a similar problem with Next 13.4.19, and it was caused by our use of node 18.16 which had a memory leak issue coming from `fetch` api. We were using node `fetch` for our graphQl links.
Bumping to node 18.17.1 fixed the issue for us